# How to prevent non-admin user from disabling the Outlook 2007Addin?

Tags: deployment, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-addin, outlook-2007-addin

As per the MSDN documentation with the Office 2007 system, office Addins are registered under HKCU and not under HKLM. I have an Outlook 2007 addin which is also registered under HKCU.

But the problem is that, even non admin users can also disable the addin since it is in HKCU. However with Outlook2003 addin this was not possible because it got registered in HKLM.

I also see some of the Outlook 2007 addins that are registered under HKLM like Microsoft VBA for Outlook Addin, Microsoft outlook Mobile service.

When a non admin user tries to disable it, outlook displays a pop up message saying that these addins are registered in HKLM and user does not have the permission to disable it.

So How can I register my Outlook 2007 addin under HKLM like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem depoying VSTO addins. I dont think that there is an way to stop it. We have had call with MS PSS around the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about adding code to the deployment/setup that changes the permissions of the registry key so that only administrative users can disable it?

The other question is what happens if you need to troubleshoot as the user?  How would you go about disabling a potential problem that your add-in may be causing?

Just my $.02.

Larry